# Pump control system without arduino

Tags: control

So i saw this schematics 
[image]
i pretty much understood it all, the comparetors, the sensors, the variable resistors , but because i am a beginner i still dont understand some things.
1- why did he use a diode?
2- why did he use a capacitor?
3- why this 1 k resistor ( circled)
4-why all those crossed connections
5- why use  a power mosfet instead of a relay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The diode is for reverse voltage protection, and to prevent the 100uF capacitor from discharging back into the motor rather than supplying power to the control circuitry.
2. The capacitor helps the control circuitry maintain a stable voltage when the motor switches on, which consumes large amounts of current and probably causes the supply voltage to drop.
3. I'd want to do some detailed analysis to be sure, but it looks like a current limiting resistor for the feedback loop around that comparator.
4. Because the circuit wouldn't work without them.
5. Because power MOSFET's consume a *lot* less power to switch than a relay, and using a relay would have required a MOSFET or BJT anyway, so just use a MOSFET and save the size and money.

Comment: As to question 4 - I think you need to find the article that originally produced the schematic. It probably discusses each of the red x's, and tells you why the circuit won't work if you break the connection there. And for question 3, the 1k/1M pair provide a small amount of hysteresis, or "snap action" for the comparator output. This will help the pump to switch on and off cleanly when the sensor reaches its trip point.

Comment: thanks, i think i will go with arduino though, the people i am gonna teach the project to are not all electrical engineering and won't be either interested or happy to learn all this theoretical stuff because it's not too easy